# Mpdf laravel taking too much to generate pdf for 50k records

Tags: laravel, mpdf

I am using Mpdf [link](https://mpdf.github.io/) for generating html to pdf in one of my website, pdf is generating fine but the problem is its taking too much time for only 50000 rows in the table, approximate 15-20 minutes.

without CSS its taking half time of it but, still its too long, there is no images in pdf only simple texts in html table.

Below I am sharing my code if some one suggest something will really helpful for me.

**Controller Code**

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '2000');
ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "100000000");   
ini_set("memory_limit","8000M");
ini_set('allow_url_fopen',1);

$data = array();
$response = array();

$paymentDue = DB::table('payment_due_view')
->select('payment_due_date', 'customer_name', 'invoice_number', 
'business_name','order_total', 'phonenumber', 'email', 'payment_status')
->where('order_total', '>', '0')
->whereNull('deleted_at')
->orderBy('payment_due_date', 'desc');

$paymentDue = $paymentDue->limit('50000');
$paymentDue = $paymentDue->get()->toArray();

$data['todaysPaymentListData'] = $paymentDue;
 
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$mpdf->useSubstitutions = false;
//$mpdf->simpleTables = false;

$html = \View::make('admin.screen.payment_due_pdf')->with('data', $data)->render();


$chunks = explode("chunk", $html);
foreach($chunks as $key => $val) {
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($val);
}

$pdfFileName = 'payment_due_report'.time().'.pdf';
$pdf_path = public_path() . '/payment-due-pdf/' . $pdfFileName;
$mpdf->Output($pdf_path, 'F');

$baseUrl = url('/');
$downloadUrl = $baseUrl.'/payment-due-pdf/'.$pdfFileName;
```

**View Code**

```
<table class="row" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" 
style="border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; border-spacing:0; max-width:100%;margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;text-align: right;padding-right: 18px;font-size: 12px !important;line-height: 20px;padding-top: 10px;"> Report Date -  {{date('m/d/Y', strtotime($reportedDate))}}</td>
    </tr>      
</table>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style='padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; text-align:center'>
        <h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 30px;"> Customer Payment Due Report </h3>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' style='border:1px solid #4E4E5B; border-bottom:0;line-height:21px;margin:auto;width:100%; background:#fff; font-size:12px;text-align:center'>
    <tr style='border-bottom: 1px dashed #CECECE;'>
        <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-top:0; border-left:0;background:#306EBA;color:#fff;'>Payment Due Date</th>
        <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-top:0; border-left:0;background:#306EBA;color:#fff;'>Due Status</th>
        <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-top:0; border-left:0;background:#306EBA;color:#fff;'>Customer Name</th>
        <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-top:0; border-left:0;background:#306EBA;color:#fff;'>Invoice Number</th>
        <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-top:0; border-left:0;background:#306EBA;color:#fff;'>Business Name</th>
        <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-top:0; border-left:0;background:#306EBA;color:#fff;'>Order Total</th>
        <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-top:0; border-left:0;background:#306EBA;color:#fff;'>Phone Number</th>
        <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-top:0; border-left:0;background:#306EBA;color:#fff;'>Email</th>          
    </tr>
    @if(isset($data['todaysPaymentListData']) && !empty($data['todaysPaymentListData']))
        @foreach($data['todaysPaymentListData'] as $val)
chunk
            @php $number = 'N/A'@endphp
            @if($val->phonenumber != '')
                @php $number = $val->phonenumber @endphp
            @endif

            @if(strtotime($val->payment_due_date) == strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))
                @php $dueStatus = 'Due Today' @endphp
            @elseif(strtotime($val->payment_due_date) > strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))
                @php $dueStatus = 'Future Due' @endphp
            @else
                @php $dueStatus = 'Past Due' @endphp
            @endif
            
            @php $businessName = 'N/A'@endphp
            @if($val->business_name != '')
                @php $businessName = $val->business_name @endphp
            @endif
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; word-wrap: break-word;">{{ \Helper::getDateTimeByTimezone($val->payment_due_date) }}</td>
                <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; word-wrap: break-word;">{{ $dueStatus }}</td>
                <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; word-wrap: break-word;">{{ $val->customer_name }}</td>
                <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; word-wrap: break-word;">{{ $val->invoice_number }}</td>
                <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; word-wrap: break-word;">{{ $businessName }}</td>
                <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; word-wrap: break-word;">${{ $val->order_total }}</td>
                <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; word-wrap: break-word;">{{ $val->phonenumber }}</td>
                <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center; border-right: 1px solid #4E4E5B; border-bottom: 1px solid #4E4E5B; word-wrap: break-word;">{{ $val->email }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</table>
```

Comment: https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/slow.html#other-things-which-are-slow

Comment: Finwe, I have checked all these things, But still same issue.

Comment: Have you read and understood it? mPDF is just slow with large tables. Don't use tables or deal with it.

Comment: Yes, Can you please suggest any other PDF plugin or any suggestion to create large number of rows like table in pdf.